# What does (fork() && fork()) || fork() print?

Tags: c, fork

Im trying to understand what this code exactly print

```
int main(void) {

    pid_t r = (fork() && fork()) || fork();

    if (r) {
        printf("a");
    } else {
        printf("b");
    }
}
```

In particular I want to understand how many "a" and "b" will be printed.
The first solution I found is: 3 "a" and 2 "b"
but Im not really sure about it, by the way I thought this could be the explanation:

The first `fork()` returns 0 to the child process (p1) and a non-zero value to the parent (p0) so the `&&` operator for the children returns 0 and the shortcircuit for `||` is taken and it needs to be evaluated.

At this point p1 will `fork()` a child process (p2) with the corresponding return values (0 for p1 and a non-zero for p2).
After this operations what follows is that the variable `r` for p1 is a non-zero value while for p2 is 0.
This means that the program will print "a" and "b".

Heading back to p0, since the left part of `&&` is non-zero values, it need to evaluate the right side, so there will be another `fork()` that will return a non-zero value to p0 and 0 to the child process (p3).
Now we need to check what happens with the `||` operator:

- p0 comes out with a non-zero value so we don't need to evaluate the right part of `||`

  - p0 will have `r` = non-zero
  - the output will be "b"
- p3 comes out with 0 and we need to evaluate the right part of the `||`

  - there will be the `fork()` call, another child (p4) will be created with return value = 0 and the `r` value for p4 will also be 0, while the `r` value for p3 will be a non-zero, so the print is "a" and "b".

I know that this kind of question has already received a reply but I just want to be sure that my reasoning makes sense.

Comment: Have the print statements include a newline and the PID and PPID (parent PID) for each line.  It would be worth capturing and printing the return value from each `fork()` too.  Beware uninitialized variables if you do that.

Comment: AFAICS, without having run the code, much less instrumented it, your analysis is correct.  You twice say that the output is “a”, and “b”; for precision, I would have preferred the precision of ‘pn prints “a” and pm prints “b”’, but that's a minor quibble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we know:

- From `man fork`: *`fork()` shall return 0 to the child process and shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent process.*
- PID is always non-zero.
- `||` and `&&` are [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
- `&&` does not execute the right side when the left side is nonzero.
- `||` does not execute the right side when the left side is zero.
- `||` is true when one of the sides is nonzero.
- `&&` is true when both sides are nonzero.
- false is zero, true is nonzero.

Ok what happens:

> ```
>  pid_t r = (fork() && fork()) || fork();
> ```

Let's summarize that into a table. Each `r =` line one `fork()` is in bold - it means this `fork()` will be executed. When a child has `fork() = 0` that means it is "spawned" - a parent has child's PID then as the return value of `fork()`.

| stage | main process | child1 | child2 | child3 | child4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r = | (**fork()** && fork()) || fork() |  |  |  |  |
| fork()= | child1pid | 0 |  |  |  |
| r = | (child1pid && **fork()**) || fork() | (0 && ignored) || **fork()** |  |  |  |
| fork()= | child2pid | child3pid | 0 | 0 |  |
| r = | (child1pid && child2pid) || ignored | (0 && ignored) || childpid3 | (child1pid && 0) || **fork()** | (0 && ignored) || 0 |  |
| fork()= |  |  | child4pid |  | 0 |
| r = | (child1pid && child2pid) || ignored | (0 && ignored) || childpid3 | (child1pid && 0) || child4pid | (0 && ignored) || 0 | (child1pid && 0) || 0 |
| r = | true || ignored | false || childpid3 | false || child4pid | false || 0 | false || 0 |
| r = | true | true | true | false | false |
| print | a | a | a | b | b |

3 times `a` and 2 times `b` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have explained it correctly.

Here is a table that can summarize the different scenarios by this code:

| r | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 0 | 0 | p1 | p1 | p1 |
| p2 | NA | NA | 0 | 0 | p2 |
| p3 | 0 | p3 | p3 | 0 | NA |

Note: `p1` refers to the first child PID, `p2` to the second child, and `p3` to the third child. `NA` indicates that the corresponding `fork()` will not be called due to short-circuit evaluation.

As you can see, the `if(r)` will be evaluated five times, three times will be taken (the `r` is evaluated as `true`) and twice will not be taken (the `r` is evaluated as false).

Answer (score 0):

You can test it yourself if you put some effort into your program:

1. Check maximum pid for your system:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

And print all `fork` return values

```
#define PIDMAX (4194304 + 1)   
//4194304 - max pid value for my system

int main(void) {

    pid_t p[3] = {PIDMAX , PIDMAX, PIDMAX};
    bool r = ((p[0] = fork()) && (p[1] = fork())) || (p[2] = fork());

    if (r) {
        printf("a\n");
    } else {
        printf("b\n");
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]); i ++)
    {
        if(p[i] == PIDMAX )  printf("N/A%s", (i == sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]) - 1) ? "\n" : ", ");
        else printf("%ld%s", (long)p[i], (i == sizeof(p) / sizeof(p[0]) - 1) ? "\n" : ", ");
    }
}
```

Output on my system:

```
a
5609, 5610, N/A
a
0, N/A, 5611
a
5609, 0, 5612
b
5609, 0, 0
b
0, N/A, 0
```

or

```
a
5733, 5734, N/A
b
0, N/A, 0
a
0, N/A, 5736
a
5733, 0, 5735
b
5733, 0, 0
```

depending on the run